# Accessing component controller from transcluded HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1XARn93mNqAit7SpYdlQ?p=preview), because the snippet editor isn't liking me today.**

## Quick Info

I'm working on using `.component()` in place of `.directive()` when using Angular 1.6 to get myself more into the type of design pattern used by Angular 2. The issue is that I cannot use any references to either `$tabs` or `$tab` (the controllers for those respective components). Nothing is output by using either `{{$tab.tabsCtrl.nothing}}` or `{{$tabs.nothing}}`.

***Please Note:this is not my actual scenario, but it does share a common problem with what I am actually doing.***

I've searched around and I get a lot of results for the Angular 2 components, but if I am being honest reading through it is basically Greek.

### Code Reference(not working in snippet editor, only for reference)

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('main.app', [])
  .component('tabs', {
    controller: function($http) {
      this.tabs = [];
      this.nothing = 'nada';
      this.addTab = function(tab) {
        this.tabs.push(tab);
      }; //end addTab
      this.selectTab = function(tab) {
        this.tabs.map(function(item) {
          item.selected = false;
        });
        var selected = this.tabs.filter(function(item) {

          return item === tab;
        });
        if (selected.length) selected[0].selected = true;
      }; //End selectTab
    },
    template: '<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justify justify-content-center"><li class="nav-item" ng-repeat="tab in $tabs.tabs" ><a href="#" ng-click="$tabs.selectTab(tab)" class="nav-link" ng-class="{\'active\':tab.selected}">{{tab.tabTitle}}</a></li></ul><div class="tabs-content" ng-transclude></div>',
    transclude: true,
    controllerAs: '$tabs'
  })
  .component('tab', {
    require: {
      'tabsCtrl': '^tabs'
    },
    bindings: {
      'tabTitle': '@',
      'selected': '<'
    },
    controller: function() {
      this.$onInit = function() {
        this.selected = this.selected || false;
        this.tabsCtrl.addTab(this);
      }; //end $onInit
    },
    transclude: true,
    controllerAs: '$tab',
    template: '<div class="tab" ng-show="$tab.selected"><div ng-transclude></div></div>'
  })
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
<tabs>
  <tab tab-title="First Tab" selected="true">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum.</h3>
      <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, in!</p>
    </div>
    some other text
  </tab>
  <tab tab-title="Second Tab">
    <strong>With a header!</strong>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 bg-primary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi, quam, quod, optio qui cum rerum vel eos rem aspernatur quia maxime incidunt numquam ipsum eum neque dicta distinctio. Minus, itaque.</div>
      <div class="col-6 bg-danger">Reprehenderit, numquam, rerum, reiciendis neque adipisci provident ea quo illo praesentium inventore fuga quisquam ducimus? Ipsum, autem, illo ullam corporis incidunt ad labore accusantium tempora officia quas quia eaque facere.</div>
    </div>
  </tab>
  <tab tab-title="Potato Tab">
    <h3>Big books {{$tabs.nothing||'nah'}}</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste quos assumenda vero fugiat officia pariatur consequatur deserunt quisquam veniam nemo?</p>
    <p>Fugiat, error, impedit, accusantium consequuntur beatae facere esse voluptatum enim animi porro commodi modi cupiditate aliquam iure ipsa. A, officiis!</p>
    <p>Architecto velit quod explicabo laborum reprehenderit culpa tempora facilis minima eum. Natus aliquid eaque laboriosam accusamus dolor hic similique ad.</p>
  </tab>
</tabs>
```

Thanks, just in case I forget to say it in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transcluded scope will be a child scope of the directive's isolate scope.

Since components use isolate scopes, you can't make use of prototypal inheritance by just doing `{{$tabs.nothing}}`. It would work if `$tabs` was exposed via `$rootScope` however, or any other non-isolate scope above tabs in the hierarchy (only `ng-app` in your example, so only `$rootScope`).

You can walk the scope chain manually.

Based on your example:

1. The current scope would be the transcluded child scope of the `tab` directive
2. The first `$parent` would be the isolate `tab` scope
3. The second `$parent` would be the transcluded child scope of the `tabs` directive
4. The third `$parent` would be the isolate `tab` scope

This gives:

```
{{$parent.$parent.$parent.$tabs.nothing}}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/jpTGVKWKEQlmGYpaeqtZ?p=preview

In most cases this isn't really a feasible solution. Probably better to expose the functionality that the transcluded content needs via a service.

Hard to give a better solution without knowing the real use case.

Comment: I think I get what you've written, but let me double check something: If I wanted to use the information that was on the `$tab` scope (a property that gets added in after some `$http` requests finish) , would that be accessed by `$parent.someProperty` ? In your own opinion, would it just be easier to use `.directives` instead?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Like this (using $timeout instead of $http): http://plnkr.co/edit/i55wN97awWrkSFY25zf1?p=preview. I would stick with `component`. I personally always try to use isolate scope with `directives`, so there wouldn't be any difference. I never use `$parent` either. I would expose what you need the transcluded content to be able to access via a tabService or similar, to make it clear that this is something anyone can inject and use, as a public api.

Comment: Alright then. Thank you verry much @tasseKATT . You have been very helpful.